# How the official Twitter mobile application connects a user?

Tags: rest, web-applications, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

I would like to know how the official Twitter Mobile Application (android/IOS) is able to connect a user without approving the application ?

Do they use their own REST API with OAuth but wich one ?
 https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

Do they use a special master key ?
Isn't it a security threat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to use OAuth interface just like any other app. If you go to the [twitter settings page](https://twitter.com/settings/applications), where you can revoke OAuth tokens, I see the mobile twitter applications there (iPhone, iPad, IOS integration) and they can be revoked.

Comment: Ok i see, thanks for your answer, now we have the proof they use their own API and OAuth but why on my android application i don't approve this app. I mean the steps C and D on this schema [link](http://drupal.jdecool.fr/sites/default/files/blog/oauth/diagram-oauth.png)